# KeyError: '"mark_seen" is an invalid parameter.' - imap_tools

Tags: python, imap, gmail-imap, imap-tools

I'm trying to find some emails in my Gmail mailbox, using imap_tools and specific criterias.
This is my code:

```
import time
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND, A

with MailBox('imap.gmail.com').login('email', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
        time.sleep(3)
        while True:
            for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(from_="some_domain", mark_seen=False)): 
        ...
```

when trying to use 'mark_seen=False' or 'reverse = True' , its giving me this error:

```
raise KeyError('"{}" is an invalid parameter.'.format(key))
KeyError: '"mark_seen" is an invalid parameter.'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to pass `mark_seen` to `fetch`, not `AND` function

Comment: wow thanks a lot, that was exactly the answer I needed, much thanks!

Comment: btw for those who may need this:
I did it like this: 
for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(from_="random_domain"), mark_seen=False)

Answer (score 0):

`mark_seen` is passed as criteria ([possible criteria](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools#search-criteria)) instead of keyword argument ([allowed kwargs](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools#basic)) to the function. It should be:

```
for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(from_="some_domain"), mark_seen=False):
```

Comment: Mmh weird, because I found these methods on https://pypi.org/project/imap-tools/

Comment: And I dont mean "seen", because that's just checking if the email was read before.

Comment: I checked the docs again and I was in confusion as well, missunderstanding you, that you wanted to add the criteria `seen`. But as I now see @crissal already corrected it. The docs you were refering to are right.